# Alias issue when find minimum

Tags: postgresql, alias

I have one query:

Partial:

```
and (("Table_Status"."Status_Lenght" - "Table_Status"."Min_Lenght" >= (select "threshold1" from "T_Everything" where "Frame" = 1 ))
```

I Like to create one Alias only from this partial.

```
"Table_Status"."Status_Lenght" - "Table_Status"."Min_Lenght" as difference
```

So I can use later the difference. But I tried many ways and I get syntax eror with the "as" command. Try to put between () also not work.
Anything helps.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only specify an alias in the `SELECT` and `FROM` clauses, not in `WHERE`. But perhaps your problem is how to use an alias defined in the `SELECT` list in a `WHERE` condition. That is not allowed, because `WHERE` comes before `SELECT`. But you can use a subquery:

```
SELECT somecolumn, difference
FROM (SELECT somecolumn,
             "Table_Status"."Status_Lenght" - "Table_Status"."Min_Lenght" AS difference
      FROM tab) AS table_alias
WHERE table_alias.difference >= 41;
```

Even though that looks complicated, PostgreSQL will “pull up” the subquery, and the query can perform well.